# How do I load an XML document into an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xcode, macos

Hi could anyone point me in the right direction with a tutorial, guide or sample code, thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by shreyasva is close but somewhat misleading.

First, parsing the XML into an easily-managed Cocoa data structure is perfectly correct. For performance reasons, you shouldn't be tying your table's datasource directly to the XML. yan.kun's suggestion is certainly possible but if you have "more than a little" data, you very well could run into performance problems. I highly recommend just parsing the data into an NSArray of NSDictionary objects for longer data sets.

Second, Core Data is a bit overkill if you don't plan to persist the XML document in some other way or if you only have a handful of objects. Overkill by a long shot. It's also not necessary (and often not reasonable) to shoehorn every data structure in your app into Core Data without good reason. An NSDictionary instance will work just fine for caching the parsed data for consumption by a table view.

Third, there is no -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. This seems to be confusing NSTableView with UITableView. Since you specified the Mac tag, look into the [NSTableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. Cocoa Bindings is not "better than" or a "replacement for" the data source protocol. It's an "alternative to". You can either load your parsed data into an NSArrayController (an array of dictionaries, one per "record", for example) and bind the table columns to it (each column is bound to a key in the dictionaries in the array controller's arrangedObjects) or just use the (easy) table data source protocol that takes literally two minutes of copy/paste from the docs to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Ill give you an idea of the architecture.

- Parse the XML using any popular XML parser `NSXMLParser` is fine.
- Store the data using core data objects, if data is not too much, keep it in memory.
- Load data in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you just want to list the content, without editing capabilities, you can load the XML into a NSXMLDocument and bind the TableView via xPath.